# How to capture WiFi-Direct probe request in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, wifi-direct, raw-sockets, wifi

I am trying to send the wifi direct probe packets using raw sockets so that mobile devices will show them in wifi direct device list.

I am trying to capture packets first in Wireshark in monitor mode in order to understand the packet structure and compare with the P2P probe request packet mentioned in [Wifi Direct specification](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xfu8d2z3q3777bx/Wi-Fi_P2P_Technical_Specification_v1.5.pdf?dl=0).

But I am not able to capture the correct probe packet in Wireshark. Can anyone suggest me what I am missing in my approach?

Comment: Can the card on the machine you are running wireshark actually understand wifi P2P?  Wifi p2p is quite new, not all cards will understand it.

Comment: I am capturing packets in mac in monitor mode.  I am able to capture every other packet on air. I just wanna create wifi direct probe packet so other devices can recognize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to capture packets with filter WLAN.addr= XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX. (Actual wifi Mac address), as WiFi Direct Mac address is different and the first byte was different.For example If your wifi mac is 00:04:CB:CX:DE:E7 then WiFi-Direct address is 02:04:CB:CX:DE:E7.

Also, I am able to show the device listed when I sent probe response packet to the device.